# Align table to the right of a page

Tags: alignment, jqplot, css-tables

I currently have an html page including a series of patterns organized as follows :

- a `div` including a `jqplot` aligned to the left of the page
- the associated table below the `jqplot`.

I'd like to align the table to the very right of the `jqplot`.
Here is a link showing the current organization for the html :

http://snovae.in2p3.fr/canto/scratch/spectra_sample/SN2007le_fullrun.html

As for now I don't have any style within the html.
The `jqplot` is called with the div and the table is not currently within any div if this helps.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give to both, div.jqplot-target and table.app a display:inline-block in the css

Comment: Thanks I didn't thought of that (but then again I'm just starting Javascript/html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your .jqplot-target elements to have a `margin-left: 0px`.
Those seem to have inline style set, act on this and set their style (which is always the same) via a css acting on their class, not on each individual elements.

Comment: For the current html it doesn't matter because I'm using a python script to generate the html so creating the style once is the same as changing the style of the dvi or else once in the function that generates the table. For most cases you're probably right though having a style predefined is probably better.

Comment: I indeed have a style defined for the jqplot div for margins (I followed your advice and set the left margin to 0).